# Print dataframe name in function output

Tags: r, function

I have a function that looks like this:

```
removeRows <- function(dataframe, rows.remove){
  dataframe <- dataframe[-rows.remove,]
  print(paste("The", paste0(rows.remove, "th"), "row was removed from", "xxxxxxx"))
}
```

I can use the function like this to remove the 5th row from the dataframe:

```
removeRows(mtcars, 5)
```

The function output this message:

```
"The 5th row was removed from xxxxxxx"
```

How can I replace xxxxxxx with the name of the dataframe I have used, so in this case `mtcars`?

Comment: Are you aware that `dataframe <- dataframe[rows.remove,]` does *not* propagate changes outside the function call? Also, `rows.remove` is supposed to be *negative*.

Comment: Post edited to `-rows.remove`. Sorry, don't understand what you mean by 'does not propagate changes outside the function call'. This is my fault, not yours. Could you expand please?

Comment: if you call `removeRows` as it stands now, R will create a copy of your `dataframe` and modify the copy. When the function terminates, the (modified) copy is destroyed, and the original `dataframe` will be untouched. If you want to change the original data, you must call it as `mtcars <- removeRows(mtcars, 5)` AND add the line `dataframe` (or `return(dataframe)`) at the end of the function code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to access the variable name in an unevaluated context. We can use [`substitute`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html) for this:

```
removeRows <- function(dataframe, rows.remove) {
  df.name <- deparse(substitute(dataframe))
  dataframe <- dataframe[rows.remove,]
  print(paste("The", paste0(rows.remove, "th"), "row was removed from", df.name))
}
```

In fact, that is its main use; as per the documentation,

> The typical use of `substitute` is to create informative labels for data sets and plots.

Comment: Are you aware of a similar idiom in Python? (OT, but I'm just wondering...)

Comment: @krlmlr Python has nothing like this – `substitute` is essentially a hack. You can however inspect the call stack in Python – it might be able to retrieve the parameter name through that but it’s going to be more complex since you’ll have to retrieve and inspect the calling context’s byte code.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that I'd be so glad to be able to write just `loginfo(expression)` instead of `loginfo("expression: %s" % expression)`... -- Just found it: In Python, there is another option to achieve this: https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tracing

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that `df.name <- deparse(substitute(dataframe))` should be used **at the top of your function** before any transformation is done. I used it right at the end of my function, just before doing ggsave, which does not return the name but somehow what is inside the dataframe, which is not what you want. This gave me a lot of headache.

So something like this :

```
function(df){
df.name <- deparse(substitute(dataframe))
ggplot()
ggsave()
}
```